# Do customers still go through a "stopped" Journey?

Tags: journeybuilder

If I "Stop" a Journey do the customers who were still in the middle of it stop receiving emails? I activated a brand new journey and the 1st step was a decision. The one who was "true" went down the path it was supposed to. The 3 who were "False" received a DE error. I want to stop this journey, fix the error, and start a brand new one. If I stop the Journey will the customer who successfully made it in and received the 1st email continue through the journey or all all processes stopped.

Comment: Create a new version of your journey and stop old version. When you do that it wi give you an option to eject all contacts.

Answer (score 0):

for any reason If you stop the journey in middle, the contacts which are still on journey will not receive the remaining emails.

in the same way if you stop only the automation associated to journey, it will stop only new contact entry to the journey but it will continue sending emails to contact which are present in the journey.